# Calculating angles to correct a projectile's path if it has tail fins

Tags: unity-game-engine, quaternions

I am trying to make a cylinder fly correctly (imagine an arrow/missile with tail fins).
We know our direction of travel and velocity as a vector3. We know our cylinder's rotation (a quaternion).
We have a corrective factor we can apply as a force, at the tail to rotate the cylinder to align with the direction of travel.

How should we calculate the vector3 (force and direction) of this force to apply at the tail?

My pseudocode/comments so far:

```cs
/* First find out the relative wind vector (inverse of our direction of travel) overal aangle of attackl (aoa) */
Vector3 RelativeWind = rb.velocity * -1;

/* Next work out current alighment of the body */
Quaternion myAlignment = rb.transform.rotation.

/* Now return a vector of the direction we need to rotate in to align with relative wind */

/* and how large this quat is (ie how far out of line we are in the 3 axis */

/* Because missile is unified cylinder, we can lookup for all axis from same curve */
/* Now compute the force applied from the lookup curve */

/* Finally multpley by the "effective Fin Force" and output as force at the centre of Lift of the
 * fin Rig - this wil then rotate the entire missile system accordingly */
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of scripting the way the force is propagated to the center of mass of the cylinder you could connect the tail to the cylinder with a joint and script only the logic of how the tail interacts with the wind